# save the state of UI elements on destroyview in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a fragment with 10 edit texts, i would like to store the text of those when the fragment is destroyed, and to be restored when it is created again. The layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
            android:textColor="#006895" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll3"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll4"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="115dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"

            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll5"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll6"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll7"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll8"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll9"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText10"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="#006895" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

as of now, i save the values of the edit text when its clicked. its ineffective, as i have to type the text, then click it again to save it. I get the text from the edit text and save it in a shared preference

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("hall", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
String name;
EditText tv = (EditText) v.findViewById(v.getId());
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.editText:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch1", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("switch1", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText2:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch2", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("switch2", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText3:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch3", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("3", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText4:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch4", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("switch4", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText5:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch5", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("switch5", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText6:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch6", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("switch6", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText7:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch7", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("switch7", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText8:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch8", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("switch8", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText9:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch9", name);
        editor.commit();
         Log.d("switch9", name);
    break;
    case R.id.editText10:
        name = tv.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("switch10", name);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("switch10", name);
    break;
 }
```

}

i tried to save the contents in the onDestroyview method. but i am unable to use findViewbyId() function as it throws errors. any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you not save an instance of the EditText objects retrieved from `findViewById()` as class variables which you access in `onDestroyView`?

Comment: @CPUTerminator should i create an array of edit texts,use     findViewByID() in    OnCreateview() method? and then use in     onDestroyView

Comment: Yeah, I would do that. You don't need to stuff them in a array if you don't want to but yes, that's perfectly valid. Regarding saving and populating data in UI elements, I'd use the method pair `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` as they are called specifically for developers to save and restore data as required. It doesn't matter if you don't use the Bundle object that is passed.